# Inkscape: 14px font bigger than I expected

Tags: inkscape

To design a website using Inkscape, I have added a 960px grid.

But, the first thing I have notice is that the 14px font seems **to big respect to the 960px grid**. I expected a smaller font. So.. why does it happen?

[image]

Comment: The only way you will get a 14px font is to design in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

The font size looks too big because it is actually set in 14 points, not 14 pixels. Inkscape text unit defaults to Point. Just change it to Pixel via the preferences panel (Shift+Ctrl+P command in Windows).
[image: Changing Inkscape text units]